# Fast shaping of multiprocessing return values in Python

Tags: python, list, multiprocessing

I have a function with list valued return values that I'm multiprocessing in Python and I need to concatenate them to 1D lists at the end. The following is a sample code for demonstration:

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp
import random as rd

N = 4
L = list(range(0, N))

def F(x):
    a = []
    b = []
    for t in range(0,2):
        a.append('a'+str(t*x))
        b.append('b'+str(t*x))
    return a, b

pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
a,b = zip(*pool.map(F, L))
pool.close()

print(a)
print(b)

A = np.concatenate(a)
B = np.concatenate(b)
              
print(A)
print(B)
```

The output for illustration is:

```
(['a0', 'a0'], ['a0', 'a1'], ['a0', 'a2'], ['a0', 'a3'])
(['b0', 'b0'], ['b0', 'b1'], ['b0', 'b2'], ['b0', 'b3'])
['a0' 'a0' 'a0' 'a1' 'a0' 'a2' 'a0' 'a3']
['b0' 'b0' 'b0' 'b1' 'b0' 'b2' 'b0' 'b3']
```

The problem is that the list `L` that I'm processing is pretty huge and that the concatenations at the end take a huge amount of time which minimizes the advantage over serial processing considerably.

Is there some clever way to avoid the concatenation or alternatively a faster method to perform the concatenation? I've been fiddling with queues but this seems kind of very slow.

Note: This seems to be a similar question as [Add result from multiprocessing into array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65686164/add-result-from-multiprocessing-into-array).

Comment: What do you need to do with the results? Will you be iterating over them or do you need them as a fully formed list?

Comment: I don't need to iterate over them. The lists are input to ```scipy.sparse.coo_matrix``` in order to instantiate a sparse matrix. In my actual implementation the multiprocessing deals with three lists, i.e. data, row indices, column indices.

Comment: Instead of using ```numpy.concatenate()``` I did experiment with ```sum(a,[])```, ```itertolos.chain()```. ```functool.reduce()``` and doing the concatenation of the resulting 2-3 lists in parallel processes. But none of those approaches has beaten ```numpy.concatenate()```.

Comment: I was going to propose `itertools.chain()`  but the `coo_matrix` constructor didn't like it - it rejects exotic types. I tried [`lazyarray`](https://lazyarray.readthedocs.io) which is supposed to be `np.array` compatible, but it too is rejected.

Comment: Exactly. The reason ```itertools.chain()``` didn't beat ```numpy.concatenate()``` is that I had to turn the iterator into a list again with ```list()```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the desired output is an input suitable for creating a `scipy.sparse.coo_matrix`, I would take a very different approach: Don't return anything, just create shared objects that can be modified directly.

What you need to create a `coo_matrix` is an array of the data values, an array of the data rows, and an array of the data columns (unless you already have another sparse matrix / dense matrix). I would create 3 shared arrays that each process can dump results directly into using the index of each entry from `L`. This even allows out of order execution, so you can use `imap_unordered` instead for better speed:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool
from multiprocessing.sharedctypes import RawArray
from random import random, randint # bogus data for testing
import numpy as np

from ctypes import c_int, c_float
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix

#pool worker globals are only global to that process
worker_globals = {}

def init_worker(data_array, row_array, col_array):
    worker_globals['data'] = np.frombuffer(data_array, dtype=c_float)
    worker_globals['row'] = np.frombuffer(row_array, dtype=c_int)
    worker_globals['col'] = np.frombuffer(col_array, dtype=c_int)

def worker_func(tup):
    i, x = tup #enumerate returns a tuple with the index then the value
    #don't bother with mutexes because we only ever write to array[i] once from a single process
    worker_globals['data'][i] = random() #calculate your data, row, and column, and write back to the shared arrays
    worker_globals['row'][i] = x
    worker_globals['col'][i] = randint(0,1000)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    L = list(range(100, 0, -1)) #some data in L
    
    data_array = RawArray(c_float, len(L))
    row_array = RawArray(c_int, len(L))
    col_array = RawArray(c_int, len(L))
    
    with Pool(initializer=init_worker, initargs=(data_array, row_array, col_array)) as p:
        for _ in p.imap_unordered(worker_func, enumerate(L)):
            pass
    d = np.frombuffer(data_array, dtype=c_float)
    r = np.frombuffer(row_array, dtype=c_int)
    c = np.frombuffer(col_array, dtype=c_int)
    mat = coo_matrix((d, (r, c)), shape=(1000, 1000))
```

By the way: You should also absolutely always be using `if __name__ == "__main__":` when using multiprocessing. It is suggested everywhere, and required on windows.

Comment: Thank you for those insights. I adopted this to my situation and it works but it is actually ~20% slower. The lists I'm processing typically have ~2^25 entries. I also increased the chunksize from 1 to 1000 as I had 50% on the cores with 1 and ~90% with 1000.

Comment: If you want better speed, you might take a look at `mp.shared_memory` and `np.ndarray` with the keyword argument `buffer`. I haven't looked into the mechanics of `RawArray` in a while, so I don't know if it's as efficient as `shared_memory`. I would also try building your own "Pool" with only the features you need to reduce overhead. Most numpy functions are implemented in c so things like `np.concatenate` are naturally fast. It can be hard to compete with that using pure python

Comment: I would guess if you can use numpy vectorization more heavily, you will usually beat any multiprocessing solution anyway

Comment: When I have a need for speed (heh :D) I usually reach first for vectorization, then `Numba`, and multiprocessing as a last resort.